# can I substitute the page number (on a page) with specific text?

Tags: header-footer

I need it because my page is written in all space, Can I setup the content of the variable where the page number are written? Or, maybe more simple, how can I write specific text on those space? I need to change it page by page. I would set it on each page

Thank you

Renato

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please see my other comment to an other question from you wrt https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 .

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that shows how to replace the page number with specific some text using `fancyhdr` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{My Text}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
This is some text.

\newpage

\section{Conclusion}
This is some more text.

\end{document}
```

If you want to replace the page number with specific text only on certain pages, you can use the `\thispagestyle` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{myfancystyle}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \rfoot{My Text}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
This is some text.

\newpage

\thispagestyle{myfancystyle}

\section{Conclusion}
This is some more text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this could work for me, but can you explain me where do I change the number 1 with "my text" and how can I made a footer for every 4 pages?